# Conditional INSERT INTO statement in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, conditional-statements, sql-insert

I'm writing a booking procedure for a mock airline booking database and what I really want to do is something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LeadCustomer 
    WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND Surname = 'Smith') 
THEN
   INSERT INTO LeadCustomer (Firstname, Surname, BillingAddress, email) 
   VALUES ('John', 'Smith', '6 Brewery close,
            Buxton, Norfolk', 'cmp.testing@example.com');
```

But Postgres doesn't support `IF` statements without loading the PL/pgSQL extension. I was wondering if there was a way to do some equivalent of this or if there's just going to have to be some user interaction in this step?

Comment: Why not just load the PL/pgSQL extension, then?

Comment: @MattBall: Working with the installation of postgres on the lab computers. Using that extension isn't in the spec.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

That specific command can be done like this:

```
insert into LeadCustomer (Firstname, Surname, BillingAddress, email)
select 
    'John', 'Smith', 
    '6 Brewery close, Buxton, Norfolk', 'cmp.testing@example.com'
where not exists (
    select 1 from leadcustomer where firstname = 'John' and surname = 'Smith'
);
```

It will insert the result of the select statement, and the `select` will only return a row if that customer does not exist.

Comment: I assume there is a (very small) race here? The select subquery runs, returns 0 rows, an insert occurs in another thread, and then the LeadCustomer insert occurs?

Comment: @Kevin A primary key exception will be raised and the application will decide what to do.

Comment: I'm confused, the question doesn't mention primary keys anywhere. If there was a primary key on (firstname, surname) why wouldn't you just try the insert first?

Comment: @Kevin I would try the insert first. The question is just about syntax.

Comment: Is there a way to insert multiple rows like this?

Comment: @CallumRogers Multiple or Single is fine. it depends on your where clause.

Comment: @CallumRogers with multiple rows this is not working

Comment: Is this query slower than simple insert query?

Answer (score 7):

> As of 9.5 version of pgsql upsert is included, using [INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

The answer below is no longer relevant.  Postgres 9.5 was released a couple years later with a better solution.

Postgres doesn't have "[upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql)" functionality without adding new functions.
What you'll have to do is run the select query and see if you have matching rows.  If you do, then insert it.

I know you're not wanting an upsert exactly, but it's pretty much the same.

Comment: this will keep on increasing the auto incremented id even when there is a conflict(as insertion is attempted)

Comment: "Check the results, and conditionally insert" is prone to race conditions: If you have two threads doing it at the same time, you can get two insertions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not in transaction (or not if it's select for update)

Answer (score -5):

-- Use follwing format to insert data in any table like this  --

create table user
(
user_id varchar(25) primary key,
phone_num numeric(15),
failed_login int not null default 0,
Login time timestamp
);

INSERT INTO USER(user_id, phone_num, failed_login, Login time)
VALUES ('12345','123456789','3',' 2021-01-16 04:24:01.755');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).