# postgres - insert gen_random_uuid() for the column "key" if the count(key) < 1

Tags: postgresql-9.4

Generate `gen_random_uuid()` for the column `key` if there `count(key) < 1`

My `table` name is `keytable` and `column` is `key`.

I am using the below `insert` statement to generate the uuid : that is the only value in the table.

```
INSERT INTO keytable VALUES(gen_random_uuid());

key 
--------------------------------------- 
5686473e-add1-4ab1-be85-7e62152ce539
```

I wanted to run this `insert` statement only when i dont have any values in my "key" column.

in other words, if `count(key) < 1` then i want to run the `INSERT INTO keytable VALUES(gen_random_uuid());`
Please help.

Comment: is your provided key a wanted value for `gen_random_uuid`?.. what is it?..

Answer (score 0):

use `INSERT ... SELECT` construct instead

```
t=# begin; insert into keytable select gen_random_uuid() where (select count(key) from keytable) < 1;
BEGIN
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into keytable select gen_random_uuid() where (select count(key) from keytable) < 1;
INSERT 0 0
t=# rollback;
ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 0):

Already Answered By Clodoaldo Neto (Link Below)

```
here is according to your perspective

insert into keytable
select gen_random_uuid()
where not exists ( select key from keytable );
```

It will only insert the result of select statement when

```
select key from keytable
```

this does not return anything!

for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15710598/8506841

Comment: @Aby If your problem is solved! please accept it as your answer.